# Pandas map two dataframes using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've two dataframes, one with text information and another with regex and patterns, what I need to do is to map a column from the second dataframe using regex

edit: What I need to do is to apply each regex on all df['text'] rows, and if there is a match, add the Pattern into a new column

Sample data

```py
text_dict = {'text':['customer and increased repair and remodel activity as well as from other sales',
             'sales for the overseas customers',
             'marketing approach is driving strong play from top tier customers',
             'employees in India have been the continuance of remote work will impact productivity',
             'sales due to higher customer']}

regex_dict = {'Pattern':['Sales + customer', 'Marketing + customer', 'Employee * Productivity'],
             'regex': ['(?:sales\\w*)(?:[^,.?])*(?:customer\\w*)|(?:customer\\w*)(?:[^,.?])*(?:sales\\w*)',
                       '(?:marketing\\w*)(?:[^,.?])*(?:customer\\w*)|(?:customer\\w*)(?:[^,.?])*(?:marketing\\w*)',
                       '(?:employee\\w*)(?:[^\n])*(?:productivity\\w*)|(?:productivity\\w*)(?:[^\n])*(?:employee\\w*)']}
```

df

```
                                                text
0  customer and increased repair and remodel acti...
1                   sales for the overseas customers
2  marketing approach is driving strong play from...
3  employees in India have been the continuance o...
4                       sales due to higher customer
```

regex

```
                   Pattern                                              regex
0         Sales + customer  (?:sales\w*)(?:[^,.?])*(?:customer\w*)|(?:cust...
1     Marketing + customer  (?:marketing\w*)(?:[^,.?])*(?:customer\w*)|(?:...
2  Employee * Productivity  (?:employee\w*)(?:[^\n])*(?:productivity\w*)|(...
```

Desired output

```
                                                text    Pattern
0  customer and increased repair and remodel acti...    Sales + customer
1                   sales for the overseas customers    Sales + customer
2  marketing approach is driving strong play from...    Marketing + customer
3  employees in India have been the continuance o...    Employee * Productivity
4                       sales due to higher customer    Sales + customer
```

tried the following, created a function that returns the Pattern in case there is a match, then I iterate over all the columns in the regex dataframe

```py
def finding_keywords(regex, match, keyword):
    if re.search(regex, match):
        return keyword
    else:
        pass

for index, row in regex.iterrows():
    df['Pattern'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: finding_keywords(regex['Regex'][index], x, regex['Pattern'][index]))
```

the problem with this is that in every iteration, it erases the previous mappings, as you can see below. As I'm foo foo was the last iteration, is the only one remaining with a pattern

```
      text      Pattern
0      foo         None
1      bar         None
2  foo foo  I'm foo foo
3  foo bar         None
4  bar bar         None
```

One solution could be to run the iteration over regex dataframe, and then iterate over df, this way I avoid loosing information, but I'm looking for a fastest solution

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do, so kindly offer a clear explanation of the problem. Also, please share the code you have tried.

Comment: I updated the description with more clarity on what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the unique values of the `regex` dataframe and apply to the `text` of the `df` frame and return the pattern in a new `regex` column. Then, merge in the `Pattern` column and drop the `regex` column.

The key to my approach was to first create the column as `NaN` and then fillna with each iteration so the columns didn't get overwritten.

```
import re
import numpy as np

srs = regex['regex'].unique()
df['regex'] = np.nan

for reg in srs:
    df['regex'] = df['regex'].fillna(df['text'].apply(lambda x: reg 
                               if re.search(reg, x) else np.NaN))

df = pd.merge(df, regex, how='left', on='regex').drop('regex', axis=1)

df

Out[1]: 
                                                text                  Pattern
0  customer and increased repair and remodel acti...         Sales + customer
1                   sales for the overseas customers         Sales + customer
2  marketing approach is driving strong play from...     Marketing + customer
3  employees in India have been the continuance o...  Employee * Productivity
4                       sales due to higher customer         Sales + customer
```